# Comparing strings to a text to set punctuation marks in the right places

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

So there's a text and phrases from this text we need to match punctuation marks to:

```
text = 'i like plums, apples, and donuts. if i had a donut, i would eat it'
phrases = [['apples and donuts'], ['a donut i would']]
```

The output I need is:

```
output = [['apples, and donuts'], ['a donut, i would']]
```

I'm a beginner, so I was thinking about using .replace() but I don't know how to slice a string and access the exact part I need from the text. Could you help me with that? (I'm not allowed to use any libraries)

Comment: Seems like an interesting homework problem. What is your attempt at the question so far? What part are you having trouble doing and/or understanding?

Comment: @costaparas so far I'm trying to create a dictionary: 'apples': 'apples, ' but when I do text.split(' '), it removes all spaces too, so after matching, I'd end up having 'apples,anddonuts'. That's why I'm thinking it might be a rather simplistic way or maybe I'm just not understanding something

Comment: You could post your existing code, to get help with that. Otherwise, an answer has kindly been posted below you can check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try regex for that

```
import re

text = 'i like plums, apples, and donuts. if i had a donut, i would eat it'
phrases = [['apples and donuts'], ['a donut i would']]
print([re.findall(i[0].replace(" ", r"\W*"), text) for i in phrases])
```

Output

```
[['apples, and donuts'], ['a donut, i would']]
```

By iterating over the `phrases` list and replacing the space with `\W*` the regex `findall` method will be able to detect the search word and ignoring the punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all the punctuation in the text and then just use the plain substring search. Your only problem then is how to restore, or to map, the text you've found to the original.

You can do it by remembering the original position in the text of each letter that you keep in the search text. Here's an example. I just removed the nested list around each phrase as it looks useless, you can easily account for it if you need.

```
from pprint import pprint

text = 'i like plums, apples, and donuts. if i had a donut, i would eat it'
phrases = ['apples and donuts', 'a donut i would']

def find_phrase(text, phrases):
    clean_text, indices = prepare_text(text)
    res = []
    for phr in phrases:
        i = clean_text.find(phr)
        if i != -1:
            res.append(text[indices[i] : indices[i+len(phr)-1]+1])

    return res

def prepare_text(text, punctuation='.,;!?'):
    s = ''
    ind = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] not in punctuation:
            s += text[i]
            ind.append(i)
    return s, ind

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(find_phrase(text, phrases))
```

['apples, and donuts.', 'a donut, i would']